# Dynamic field calculations in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm making a todo list in django. I have a model with some properties:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Action Name", max_length=200, unique = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Complete?")

    effort = models.IntegerField("Effort Level", choices = LEVELS, default = 3)
    importance = models.IntegerField("Importance", choices = LEVELS, default = 3)
    enjoyment = models.IntegerField("Enjoyment", choices = LEVELS, default = 3)

    days_to_expiration = models.IntegerField("Days to Expiration", choices = DAYS_TO_EXPIRATION, default = 7)

    reset_date = models.DateField("Date of Action Reset", blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to sort based on priority.  I define priority as:

```
priority = (1 + (today's date - reset_date) / days_to_expiration) * importance
```

This just scales up importance based on how "overdue" the task is.

Now when I pull a list of incomplete actions, I can calculate this priority number for each action item, but that doesn't seem efficient since I will end up calculating the same numbers multiple times.  I could define a new field in the model:

```
priority = models.DecimalField("Priority", max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, blank = True, null = True)
```

and schedule a function to run once a day to calculate the new priority per task.

**But I want to know if it's possible to program the priority calculation directly into the model.  So the priority field in the Action model is necessarily by design a function of importance and days_to_expiration.  It would be updated dynamically using the values of importance, days_to_expiration, and today's date.  That way, priority would always be calculated automatically when I need it.  Is this a possibility?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def priority(self):
        return (1 + (date.today() - self.reset_date) / self.days_to_expiration) * self.importance
```

Then, you can access it like any other attribute on your model

```
priority = my_model.priority
```

Comment: I don't think this really addresses the problem; you still compute `priority` every time.

Comment: That seems to be what the OP wants: "That way, priority would always be calculated automatically when I need it."

Comment: Now that you mention it, I see isbadawi's point that it would amount to the same: priority will be computed multiple times when not strictly necessary.  But this was the idea I was envisioning.

Comment: two things.  First, I needed to alter the equation to include ".days" ((1 + (date.today() - self.reset_date).days / self.days_to_expiration) * self.importance).  But more importantly, when the sort is resolved, I get an error that the field is not a viable option: Action.objects.all().order_by('priority').  Is there a way to sort on this property?

Comment: @Ed. If you go this way, then `property` doesn't exist at the database level so you can't use it in an `order by` clause. You can do the sort in python, e.g. with `sorted(Action.objects.all(), key=lambda a: a.priority)`, but this is less efficient than a database sort.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization); `priority` is a denormalized field. You can probably hack around with signals, or extend `save` methods, or maybe use manager methods in some clever way to achieve this, but a nice alternative is to use [django-denorm](http://initcrash.github.com/django-denorm/). The tutorial goes through a situation very similar to yours.

Comment: this is really interesting.  I wonder though if django-denorm can create a dependency on date?  So when the date changes, would the priority field get updated as well?

Comment: @Ed. You could set it up so it updates every day, if that's what you're asking. See the example with the daemon at the end

Answer (score 1):

I know its old , but I've faced a similar issue and solve it by overriding the default Manager of the model and overriding its get_queryset method then annotate the field in the database level .

something like

```
class ActionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            priority=ExpressionWrapper(
                (1 + (datetime.now().date() - F('reset_date')) / F('days_to_expiration')) * F('importance'),
                output_field=models.DecimalField()
            )
        )
```

haven't test it but you should know the context